# Why was my question on compatibility flagged as a "Hardware Purchasing Question"?

Tags: discussion

I am new to this Stack Exchange site. I recently asked a question about whether certain connections were standardized, specifically laptop 4k non-touch screens. It quickly got flagged as an off-topic question for the reason of being a "Hardware Purchasing Question."

I was not asking for specific hardware recommendations. I was simply asking whether a class of connectors were cross compatible.

I would like to know why my question is off topic.

Was it because of the context?  I gave some context for my question because, on other stack exchanges, when ever I don't explain why I want what I want, I end up in long conversations justifying why I want what I want.  So I added a context to explain the problem which led me to asking this question.  This context does mention purchasing, but only as a segue in to the actual specific question.  Specifically, "Before I spend money on the actual hardware, I would like to be a bit more certain [about the compatibility]."

Would it be on topic if I removed the context? Because I actually am usually helped by questions that give context, as I can more easily determine if they are actually asking the question I want answered.

*[4k laptop monitor compatibility with LCD control boards](https://superuser.com/questions/1376085/4k-laptop-monitor-compatability-with-lcd-control-boards)*

Comment: "Purchasing" questions can cover a lot of ground. They aren't necessarily limited to requests for product recommendations. The primary issue with them is that any answers won't be long-lasting because of how fast things change. So a lot of questions get closed under the umbrella of a purchasing question if they involve requests for product information and are tied to the current state of things. That's largely the issue with your question. I voted to reopen because in this case, there's really only one answer, and it won't change over time (see comment and answer there).

Comment: @fixer1234 The traditional view has been that asking for *recommendations* is right out (it's too personalised and too time-localised) but generally asking about *compatibility* is fine because it will always be relevant, even if only in a retro hardware sense 10 years later. Unfortunately a lot of close-voters mix these two cases up.